# Adding Tooltips to individual words in a TreeViewer

Tags: java, swt, tooltip, jface

I've got a TreeViewer window containing a `Tree`, and I would like to create ToolTips that appear when hovering over specific words.

So far, I have only been able to add tooltips to entire lines at once using `ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor()`, however this does not suit my needs.

How can I have different tooltips for each separate word?

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this ... but if you can get the Label object that represents an item in the tree viewer, you could try attaching a [MouseTrackListener](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#addMouseMoveListener%28org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseMoveListener%29) and do your own tooltip.